# Extract irregularly shaped region from image using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to learn OpenCV as I have an interest in Computer Vision and one kind of issue I am trying to tackle is extracting irregularly shaped regions from a given image. For example if I have a picture of this shoe:

[image]

Is there a way in which I can apply a mask to the image to extract ONLY the big Nike logo from the shoe image? Any insight will be much appreciated!

Comment: Very difficult to do a black shoe with a black shadow. Best approach is Deep Learning / AI which needs lots of training images. See for example http://remove.bg

Comment: maybe ask on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or on [forum OpenCV](https://forum.opencv.org/)

Comment: you might be able to get some results using pattern matching. Download a nike logo from google and try pattern matching with that.

Comment: Please undelete your recent question.